# Eclipse Foundation command line import throws error

Tags: cmd, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to automatize some stuff in my development process. I find myself constantly generating new workspaces with projects from repositories and importing them to eclipse.

I can import and build the projects properly with SVN and Maven. But I have to manually import the projects to Eclipse. I tried writing a batch file to import based on parameters, but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized. Will retry after the state location is initialized.
```

While eclipse throws this error:

```
The folder "path\to\workspace" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import path\to\project\.metadata" is read-only`
```

The command I use is

`call path\to\eclipse\eclipsec.exe --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -data` `"path\to\workspace\" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import` `path\to\project`

The eclipse I use is Eclipse Foundation 2019/12, JDK 1.8. I'm also using this plugin https://github.com/seeq12/eclipse-import-projects-plugin which should do the trick, but for some reason I don't know it fails.

What could I do to fix this? Is there any other option? I really want to just use a batch file.

Thanks.

Comment: First one is a warning not an error. The second one tells you can't write to disk where you are trying to. You need to read errors. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/decoding-errors.html on decoding Windows' errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a closer look at this part of your command line:

```
[...] -data "path\to\workspace\" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import path\to\project
```

A backslash is often treated as an escape character. In this case, I suspect it's escaping the subsequent quote character, causing it to be treated as a literal quote character that appears in the workspace path, rather than terminating the workspace path argument. Since the workspace path argument begins with a quote, the subsequent arguments all get interpreted as part of the workspace path, such that Eclipse thinks the complete workspace path is:

```
path\to\workspace\" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import path\to\project
```

which obviously doesn't exist.

Doubling up the backslashes will likely fix the problem:

```
call path\\to\\eclipse\\eclipsec.exe --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -data "path\\to\\workspace\\" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import path\\to\\project
```

Now, for every `\\` pair, the first backslash escapes the second, resulting in a literal backslash, which is what you want.

Welcome to programming on Windows, which chooses as its path separator a character that the rest of the world has chosen as its escape character :)

Comment: This solved my problem with the non-writable location (more like a non-existant location). Though now I have a problem with java projects, this answer is the correct.